# Convergence of a sequence to a limit from the bounds of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have been working of and on on this problem for the past couple of days and would like some help where I am stuck.

The Problem: Let $u_{n}$ be  for all $n \in \Bbb N\backslash\{0\}$ be a sequence of real numbers defined such that, for every $m \in \Bbb N \backslash\{0\}$,  $$ 0\leq u_{n+m}\leq (m+n)/(mn)$$

Show that $u_{n}$ converges to 0.

I believe that showing that the upper bound converges to 0 of $u_{n+m}$  will  imply that $u_{n}$ converges to 0. This is what I have started off doing. $$|m+n/mn|=m/mn +n/mn=1/n+1/m$$I know that as n gets very large 1/n will get very small. The issue arises when looking at 1/m because I can not choose m and the upper bound of the term 1/m is 1. Any epsilon I add to 1 will always be bigger than epsilon. How do I get myself out of this pickle, or have I gone down the wrong path completely.

Comment: Why can't you choose $m$?  For example $u_{2k} = u_{k+k}$.

Comment: Well at least the way I understand it $u_{n+m}$ must satisfy the inequality for all m. while n gets very large m could be anything even 1.

Comment: Yes, and so $u_{2k}=u_{k+k} \leq 1/k + 1/k$.  I am using the fact that it holds for all positive integers $m$ by choosing positive integers $m$ that are convenient for me (I choose $m=k$).  You are choosing $m=1$ which seems to be optimally inconvenient.  In other words, if you always choose $m=1$ you cannot solve the problem and you will not be using the full information given to you in the problem (it holds _for all $m$_, not just $m=1$).

Comment: I also realized that I did not right out the complete question. Just edited to correct. Unsure if that changes anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use particular values of $m,n$ for given $m+n$. We obviously take $m,n$ as nearly equal as possible. So we get:

$$0\le u_{2n}\le \frac{2}{n}\le\frac{6}{2n}\text{ and }0\le u_{2n+1}\le\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\le\frac{6}{2n+1}$$ So for all $n$ we have $0\le u_n\le\frac{6}{n}$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=0$.